# Помогите создать свой датасет как MNIST

Tags: java, машинное-обучение, dataset

Не могу найти мануал,в котором объясняется как создать и сохранить свой датасет.
Я реализовал нейронную сеть, на данный момент она натренированна на MNIST,но я хочу создать свой датасет из популярных шрифтов для распознавания русских символов и цифр (печатных). Готового датасета я не нашел. Буквы с цифрами нарезал и раскидал по папкам. Мой проект на JavaEE.Нарезку делал на питоне.
Про мнист пишу т.к. создан класс с работой в его формате (t10k-images-idx3-ubyte, t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte, train-images-idx3-ubyte, train-labels-idx1-ubyte)

Comment: *Буквы с цифрами нарезал и раскидал по папкам* — ну так датасет создан. Может вам что-то другое надо?

Comment: Как мне разделить их на  - метки и картинки,я так понимаю метки должны быть связаны с картинками.В идеале я хотел бы два архива как в мнисте.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас есть только изображения без их разметки? Тогда датасет не создан. Надо сделать отображение i-ой картинки в нужную метку. Это можно сделать различными способами, например, картинки `1_xxxx.jpg` показывают цифру `1`

Comment: Да,разметки у меня нету,наименования файлов я сделаю.Еще что нибудь надо делать,что бы возможно было натренировать сеть?( Я не доконца понимаю как в мнисте организована связь картинка - метка)

Comment: Часто исходный датасет уже разбивают на тренировочную/тестовую выборки, но это необязательно. Можете посмотреть примеры датасетов на https://www.kaggle.com/ и сделать похожим образом, кстати

Comment: А как в мнисте связаны набор данных с метками,это же разные файлы?Кэгл посмотрю,спасибо.

Comment: MNISTы разные бывают :) В классическом уже не помню, посмотрите на сайте описание датасета, в Kannada-MNIST, который у меня сейчас есть, это два csv файла, где отображение задаётся так: i-ая строка первого файла имеет i-ую метку из второго

Comment: Кстати может быть встречали готовый датасет печатных русских букв?.

Comment: https://github.com/GregVial/CoMNIST, но это уже другой по смыслу вопрос, так что стоит задавать его отдельно